# Get user properties of current user in SharePoint Online (hosted app)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to get the user properties of the current user using javascript.

In C# i can easily do it using event receivers on itemadding. However i want to use javascript in order to get the user properties and it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting errors.

Here is the code :

```
 function getCurrentUserInformation() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);

    var userProperties = ["InitialLeaveDays", "LeaveDays"];

    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new UserProfilePropertiesForUser(context, currentUser, userProperties);

    context.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);

}
```

I'm getting error on peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context); stating that can't get of undefined or null . Don't know what is wrong .

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the correct user information. You need to pass the actual user login name. Also, you need to wait for the `SP.UserProfile.js` to be loaded before you execute your `getMyProperties` function.

Add/Ensure  the below references in your sharepoint hosted app page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.UserProfiles.js"></script>
```

Try the below code:

```
function getUserProperties() {
    var userProfileProperties;

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    var currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var loginName = currentUser.get_loginName();

        var profilePropertyNames = ["InitialLeaveDays", "LeaveDays"];
        var userProfilePropertiesForUser = 
            new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
                clientContext,
                loginName,
                profilePropertyNames);

        userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

        clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            console.log("initial leave days :" + userProfileProperties[0]);
            console.log("leave days :" + userProfileProperties[1]);
        }, function(sender, args){
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });

    },function(sender, args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Also, ensure that your sharepoint hosted app has permission to read user profiles as below in your appmanifest.xml file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply . However the command SP.SOD.executeFunc won't execute my function . The breakpoint never hits my function.

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked! Much appreciate it for your help